# How to set value for the input value in the element from Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am the very beginner for html and js.
I have a js which can set the value of id="tk___kiaVlink" by using the following.

```
this.form.formElements.get('tk___kiaVlink').update('abcedf ghi');
```

But both label and link values are updated. How could I specify js code to update only [link] value?

```
<div class="fabrikSubElementContainer" id="tk___kiaVlink">
<input type="text" name="tk___kiaVlink[label]" size="200" maxlength="200" class="form-control fabrikinput inputbox fabrikSubElement" placeholder="Label" value="Video">
<input type="text" name="tk___kiaVlink[link]" size="200" maxlength="200" class="form-control fabrikinput inputbox fabrikSubElement" placeholder="URL" value="test value">
```

I tried using the name tk___kiaVlink[label] and it doesn't work.

Comment: you could simply try `document.getElementsByName('tk___kiaVlink[label]').value='abcdef ghi'`

Comment: Thanks Jijo. I tried to fix as you have mentioned. But it still didn't work. Code from Angel (below) works but with warning. I'll find it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [label, link] = [...document.querySelectorAll('#tk___kiaVlink input')];
[label.value, link.value] = ['my label value', 'my link value'];
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but some warning message came up. I am using Joomla CRM and it 's component Fabrik form. The JS code is in its element. Warning is "Expected an identifier and instead saw '['. const '{a}' is initialized to 'undefined'. Missing semicolon. Bad assignment. I'll have to find out more for that warning.

Comment: document.querySelector('#tk___kiaVlink input:nth-child(2)').value = 'some string';
Maybe try this one only for the link.

Comment: It works with the code above . No warning messages :)